# Paste tab seperated string into one cell in Excel

Tags: excel

Is it possible to copy and paste a string containing tab seperated values in to one cell in Excel.

For example, I have the following string :

```
Height   1420mm
Width   440mm
```

I need to copy this to one excel cell and keep the tabs inbetween. Currently, it handles them as a space, which is not what I want.

Comment: Google gave me this: https://www.wikihow.com/Copy-Paste-Tab-Delimited-Text-Into-Excel

Comment: @Kershrew not what I need. This pastes over multiple cells, i need it in one

Comment: Yes but you can use this information to make excel ignore the tab as a delimiter and that resolves your problem. See https://superuser.com/questions/422137/pasting-text-into-excel-without-splitting-on-spaces-or-other-delimiter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Data tab> Text to column

Make sure to **uncheck** the tab as one of the delimiters.

Basically, when you paste a string with tab character, it will paste into multiple cells if the tab delimiter is checked. Make sure it is turned off.

[image]

Comment: That looks perfect, but when I click the 'text to columns' i get 'No data was selected to parse'. I want to copy it from outside of Excel, into Excel ? Any ideas ?

Comment: You need to select a cell that has value in it before navigating to that dialog box. It doesn't matter what the cell value is. Your aim is just to open that dialog and uncheck the 'tab' delimiter and you're good to go.

Comment: When I single click on the cell and paste it removes the tabs completely so {height    1420mm} now becomes {height1420mm} ?

Comment: It looks like the 'tab' character is gone but actually it's still in there. Try to copy paste the cell into a notepad for example and you'll see that it's there.

Comment: Looks like I have another problem now, where the new line separates them to new lines in the excel. (I have a list of properties and values I wish to put into one cell). Looks like this isn't going to work. but you have solved what I have asked. Thanks for that

Comment: I see. Are you pasting it manually? Because if it is being done manually per cell, then pasting the value with newline char into the "Formula Bar" will do the trick. Let me know.

Comment: yes manually, but there are a lot of them. I've resorted to writing a powershell script that takes the string of properties and values and parses them to what I need and I can paste it directly in to one cell. Works well, just an extra step I didn't really want to take. Appreciate the help